# undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz' ARM program for STM32

Tags: c, arm, stm32

I am working on a college project that includes working with 6 digit 7 seg display. I wrote a code that should write the double number on display but I can't send the double to function nor convert double to int and then send it.

I working in Eclipse and Proteus.

Here is the code:

```c
    void ispisbroja(int broj){

    int c4 = (broj%1000000)/100000;
    int c3 = (broj%100000)/10000;
    int c2=(broj%10000)/1000;
    int c1=(broj%1000)/100;
    int c0=(broj%100)/10;
    int cm1=(broj%10);

    while(1){
        GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS0); // setujemo pin PC0
    switch(c4){
    case 9:
        devetka();
        break;
    case 8:
        osmica();
        break;
    case 7:
        sedmica();
        break;
    case 6:
        sestica();
        break;
    case 5:
        petica();
        break;
    case 4:
        cetvorka();
        break;
    case 3:
        trojka();
        break;
    case 2:
        dvojka();
        break;
    case 1:
        jedinica();
        break;
    default:
        nula();
    }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS0); // resetujemo pin PC0
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR0); // resetujemo pin PC0

    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS1); // setujemo pin PC1
    switch(c3){
        case 9:
            devetka();
            break;
        case 8:
            osmica();
            break;
        case 7:
            sedmica();
            break;
        case 6:
            sestica();
            break;
        case 5:
            petica();
            break;
        case 4:
            cetvorka();
            break;
        case 3:
            trojka();
            break;
        case 2:
            dvojka();
            break;
        case 1:
            jedinica();
            break;
        default:
            nula();
        }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS1); // resetujemo pin PC1
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR1); // resetujemo pin PC1

    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS2); // setujemo pin PC2
    switch (c2){
        case 9:
            devetka();
            break;
        case 8:
            osmica();
            break;
        case 7:
            sedmica();
            break;
        case 6:
            sestica();
            break;
        case 5:
            petica();
            break;
        case 4:
            cetvorka();
            break;
        case 3:
            trojka();
            break;
        case 2:
            dvojka();
            break;
        case 1:
            jedinica();
            break;
        default:
            nula();
        }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS2); // resetujemo pin PC2
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR2); // resetujemo pin PC2

    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS3); // setujemo pin PC3
    switch(c1){
        case 9:
            devetka(1);
            break;
        case 8:
            osmica(1);
            break;
        case 7:
            sedmica(1);
            break;
        case 6:
            sestica(1);
            break;
        case 5:
            petica(1);
            break;
        case 4:
            cetvorka(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            trojka(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            dvojka(1);
            break;
        case 1:
            jedinica(1);
            break;
        default:
            nula(1);
        }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS3); // resetujemo pin PC3
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR3); // resetujemo pin PC3


    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS4); // setujemo pin PC4
    switch(c0){
        case 9:
            devetka();
            break;
        case 8:
            osmica();
            break;
        case 7:
            sedmica();
            break;
        case 6:
            sestica();
            break;
        case 5:
            petica();
            break;
        case 4:
            cetvorka();
            break;
        case 3:
            trojka();
            break;
        case 2:
            dvojka();
            break;
        case 1:
            jedinica();
            break;
        default:
            nula();
        }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS4); // resetujemo pin PC4
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR4); // resetujemo pin PC4

    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BS5); // setujemo pin PC5
    switch(cm1){
        case 9:
            devetka();
            break;
        case 8:
            osmica();
            break;
        case 7:
            sedmica();
            break;
        case 6:
            sestica();
            break;
        case 5:
            petica();
            break;
        case 4:
            cetvorka();
            break;
        case 3:
            trojka();
            break;
        case 2:
            dvojka();
            break;
        case 1:
            jedinica();
            break;
        default:
            nula();
        }
    delay(100);
    GPIOC->BSRR &= ~(GPIO_BSRR_BS5); // resetujemo pin PC5
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (GPIO_BSRR_BR5); // resetujemo pin PC5
    }

}


int main(void){


    GPIO_Init();
    double broj = 1234.66;
    int broj2=broj;
    broj2 = broj2 * 100;
    ispisbroja(broj2);

}
```

error I got:

```
D:\toolchain\GNU MCU Eclipse\ARM Embedded GCC\8.3.1-1.1\bin/arm-none-eabi-ld.exe -T linker_script.ld -o build/domzad2_program.elf build/startup_code.o build/main.o build/util.o build/timer_pwm.o build/adc.o build/usart.o
D:\toolchain\GNU MCU Eclipse\ARM Embedded GCC\8.3.1-1.1\bin/arm-none-eabi-ld.exe: build/main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xdd4): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
make: *** [makefile:92: build/domzad2_program.elf] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is a very long code example. I am sure you could cut it down by 95% to still reproduce your problem. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update accordingly.

Comment: ld does not know where libraries are, gcc does so either use gcc to link, or specifically add the gcc libraries to the ld command line.

Comment: What exact STM32 MCU are you using? Most likely you just need a compiler flag like `-mpu=cortex-m0plus` as `__aeabi_xxx` functions are implemented by the compiler toolchain.

Comment: Its STM32F106R6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also to link the libraries. It is quite difficult to explain in a simple post how to configure the toolchain.

I would suggest installing stmCubeIde which will do the configuration for you.